# Passport.js custom callback passing parameter

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I have this code so far

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }), function(req, res) {
        return res.redirect('/profile/' + req.user.username);
    });
```

A successful login is working. However, when the login fails, it gets redirected via `GET` request to `/login`. So I'd need some additional code like this to handle that situation:

```
app.get('/login', ...);
```

I need to implement this in such a way that if the `POST` fails and redirects to this `GET` it will send the username that made it fail. This is so I can populate the username back into the form so it doesn't get cleared everytime someone tries to log in unsuccessfully due to an incorrect username.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: This is how I wrote my strategy.

---

`passport.use(User.createStrategy());`

---

User.js

---

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    dateOfBirth: Date,
    email: String,
    mobileNumber: Number,
    favouriteWebsite: String,
    favouriteColour: String
});

User.methods.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
User.methods.getAge = function() {
    return ~~((Date.now() - new Date(this.dateOfBirth)) / (31557600000));
}

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameQueryFields: ["username", "email"], // TODO not working
    errorMessages: {
        IncorrectPasswordError: "Incorrect password!",
        IncorrectUsernameError: "Username does not exist!"
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `passport.authenticate` yourself with `(req, res, next)`. It accepts a callback function as its input so you can determine if the process was successful or not.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) {
      // failed
    } else {
      // successful
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

You might want to handle `err` and `!user` (`user === false`) separately. `err` means there was some internal errors in the process, but user would be `false` when the user doesn't exist. It depends how you wrote the strategy though.

Comment: @Amir Please see my edit to see how I wrote the strategy

Comment: @Ogen do you also have `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));` somewhere? The code in my answer should work if other things have setup correctly. You can handle `err` case with showing an `internal error` message to user and `!user` with `wrong username/password` for example. And also `console.log` the `err` if it exists to see the cause.